# gnome-builder don't find my glade file

Tags: c, linux, gtk, glade, gnome-builder

I try to write GUI programs with gnome-builder and try to make the layout with Glade. I made a tutorial on [Programmer's Notes](https://prognotes.net/2015/06/gtk-3-c-program-using-glade-3/%22optional%20title%22).

### C

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    GError          *err = NULL;
    GtkBuilder      *builder;
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "window_main.ui", &err);

    if (err != NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read file: %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free(err);
        return 1;
    }

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));

    if (window == NULL || !GTK_IS_WINDOW(window)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to get window. (window == NULL || window != GtkWindow)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void on_window_main_destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data){
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

### Glade

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding="UFT-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="title" translatable="yes">Test Window</property>
        <property name="default_width">640</property>
        <property name="default_height">480</property>
        <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
        <child>
            <placeholder/>
     </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

The .glade file is located in the src/ direction like the .c file.
When I run the code, following error message returns
`Unable to read file: Failed to open file “./window_main.ui”: No such file or directory`

I don't know where I should put the glade file, because when I compiled my self with
`gcc  main.c -Wall 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0' -export-dynamic`
and run it with `./a.out` the window opens without any error.

Comment: I don't use Gnome Builder but probably the build output location is not the same and therefore it will not find it. Check the build output in gnomebuilder and try to find the location of the build, maybe in some cache folder or temporary folder somewhere.

Comment: Ideally you use GResource, not opening a relative path by hand.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [TingPing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894154/gnome-builder-dont-find-my-glade-file#comment78759284_45894154) in comment area, the best way is to include it in [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html). In your case, the resource specification XML would be like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/main">
    <file>window_main.ui</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

And you load the resource with [`gtk_builder_new_from_resource()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-new-from-resource), like

```c
GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_resource("/main/window_main.ui");
```

Comment: Could you show a demo to explain how to use GResource in Gnome Builder, I still can not find the file, even after use "glib-compile-resources --generate  gresource.xml "

Comment: @Honghe.Wu You can try `--generate-source` and `--generate-header` so you can statically link them like any other C source code.

Comment: I have sent the detail problem to you email -- zyu13ATbinghamton with posted the code in Github, Can you check the mail in your free time.Thanks!

Comment: @Honghe.Wu This is a question for C and you sent me an email about Python (I assume that’s [PyGTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyGTK)). Sorry that I’m not familiar with PyGTK. Please make it a separate question with the [tag:pygtk] tag.